# need tutorials on boost's synchronizations objects

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, thread-safety, boost-thread

well the docs on boost's thread lib isn't as good as the asio lib...
And after reading this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html I got the main idea but there is no codes and examples, that I could find, using that.
I would be happy for a link or explanations on how using that..

Comment: Possible duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials

Comment: @DumbCoder that isn't updated... new version changed a lot of stuff in the way threading works, I looked at it before posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two tutorials might help as they have code examples.

- [this](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/) has a section on multithreading which gives an intro to synchronization objects
- [Another](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=R3B4KSRI4FNXBQE1GHRSKH4ATMY32JVN?articleId=184401518&dept_url=/cpp/-) one from Dr. Dobb's has an intro.

Comment: is it updated for the latest boost's version? cuz as I wrote, a lot has changed in threads in the last versions. Tnx a lot!

Comment: The Dr. Dobb's article mentions an update at the end to address the latest changes. I remember seeing an updated article and google should lead you there if you search using the title. Hope this helps.